# Selectively access rows of numpy 3D matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, matrix-indexing

Is there a way to index a 3D numpy matrix to selectively grab the i'th row of each i'th layer?

e.g. I have an RxNxR matrix, and I want to grab the 1st row of the 1st layer, the 2nd row of the 2nd layer, the 3rd row of the 3rd layer, etc. and end up with an RxN matrix.

Can I do that in a single operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using  the [numpy.diagonal](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html) function:

```
a = np.arange(27).reshape(3, 3, 3)
np.diagonal(a, offset=0, axis1=0, axis2=1).T
```

gives

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [24, 25, 26]])
```

Comment: can this possibly be generalized to also work with the case where R = 1? say I have a 1x3x1 matrix, this command is giving me only the first element, not the full row.

Comment: It works if the matrix is 3x1x1... Which dimension corresponds to the layers? or you can try `np.diagonal(a, offset=0, axis1=0, axis2=2)`

Comment: That did the trick! (the layers are the third dimension). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do the trick:

```
import numpy as np
matrix = ...
result = np.zeros((matrix.shape[0], matrix.shape[1]))

for i in range(0, len(matrix)):
    result[i] = matrix[i][i]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a comprehension - depends on which dimensions you define as your 'layer', etc but this would work:

```
a = np.array([...])

[a[:, i, 0] for i in range(np.shape(a)[1])]
```